# Honda Accord 2017 Radio Black screen

Tags: honda, audio, accord, hybrid

I have a Honda accord hybrid 2017 and I was checking the hidden screen settings and suddenly the screen went all black as attached pictures can you please help me with resetting the radio screen or check how we can solve this issue, and for info, the rear camera and right camera are working fine

[image]Thank you

Comment: Very simple find the accessories box under the steering and disconnect the radio unit fuse and reconnect it after 50 seconds. Usually some models require a code after this just in case get in touch with the dealership about the code.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work if you know any other solution, please reply

Comment: Last hope before you hand this over to the dealership, 1. Hold the power button for 2-seconds and release it after the beep. Do this in accessories mode. In case it doesn’t beep after 2 seconds, let go of it, and power off the car and then re-enter the accessories mode and continue to hold down the power button on the system until you hear a beep.

Comment: I've tried this and unplugged all the USP portals it didn't work either

Comment: Apologies, now you’ll just have to await until the dealership reopens.